# What is the query for getting user location from this database schema?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables - USERS, CITIES, STATES, COUNTRIES

```
USERS( user_id, email, password, name, location(FK) [references city_id] )

CITIES( city_id, name, state_id(FK), country_id(FK) ) 

STATES( state_id, name, country_id(FK) )

COUNTRIES( country_id, name )
```

**I want to select username with complete location (eg: ADAM New Delhi, Delhi, India)**

What is the optimal query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below script

```
SELECT A.name USERS,
B.name CITIES,
C.name STATES,
D.name COUNTRIES
FROM USERS A
INNER JOIN CITIES B ON A.location = B.city_id
INNER JOIN STATES C ON B.state_id = C.state_id
INNER JOIN COUNTRIES D ON C.country_id = D.country_id
```

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped. You can also out an up vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are keys or something else not show on the question, this is a trivial join:

```
SELECT u.name, c.name, s.name, co.name 
FROM USERS u
JOIN CITIES c ON (u.city_id=c.city_id)
JOIN STATES s ON (s.state_id=c.state_id)
JOIN COUNTRIES co ON (co.country_id=s.country_id);
```